# JBoss AS7 Deployment Plugin (jboss-as-maven-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jboss

I have tried everything i can think of to get my JBoss to run as a plugin with maven, but it seems impossible to get it tio run. I get the same error on all versions(tried 7.1.1 - 7.9 final).

Does anyone now what can be the problem? I am running on Java 8 and maven 3.

I have also tried all possible ports, 9999, 9990, 4447 and so on. Running in standalone mode. This seems to be a really horrible plugin.

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:4447. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

For a default standalone.xml configuration (with 0 port offset) remote management port is 9999.
You need to set this port in jboss maven plugin configuration.

Usually, in this cases you need to check:
1- Plugin configuration matches your jboss standalone xml file. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.9.Final</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>${jboss.hostname}</hostname>
        <port>${jboss.port}</port>
        <username>${jboss.user}</username>
        <password>${jboss.pass}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2 - check if hostname matches the binding interface where your jboss AS is listening. For example using netstat command you can check if jboss is listening in 0.0.0.0:9999 or 127.0.0.1:9999 or another interface.

This ip should be setted in jboss.hostname property and the default port 9999 in jboss.port property.

jboss.user and jboss.pass properties are related to your defined management user in jboss AS.

3 - try to execute mvn jboss-as:deploy. If you get a timeout error message try increasing timeout value in the plugin configuration. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.9.Final</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>${jboss.hostname}</hostname>
        <port>${jboss.port}</port>
        <username>${jboss.user}</username>
        <password>${jboss.pass}</password>
```

....
            30000
....

4 - if problem persist, check your firewall configuration too.